# Are there examples of symbols similar to modern emoji or emoticons that were used before 20th century?

Tags: writing-systems, symbol

In other words, any symbols (ideograms) used to convey emotions that fit the description of "ancient emoji".

I'm mostly interested in ancient and medieval attested symbols, but anything from before XX century will be helpful.

Comment: Not really, in English, according to this. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emoticon#History

Comment: @sumelic, yes, before 1900's (roughly). P.S. Hm it's strange, I always use and see centuries in Roman numerals, never noticed it's uncommon. Ok then...

Comment: Related: https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/2742/